# Installing Nginx on DigitalOcean Debian 8.5 fails with "Unmet dependencies"

Tags: nginx, debian

I am trying to install Nginx-full on my Debian 8.5 x64 machine, hosted by DigitalOcean like so:

> sudo apt-get install nginx-full

but I am receiving the following error:

> ~>Reading package lists... Done
>   ~>Building dependency tree
>   ~>Reading state information... Done
>   ~>You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
>   ~>The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>   ~>atom :
>          Depends: gconf2 but it is not going to be installed
>          Depends: gconf-service but it is not going to be installed
>          Depends: libnotify4 but it is not going to be installed
>          Depends: libxtst6 but it is not going to be installed
>          Depends: libnss3 but it is not going to be installed
>          Depends: gvfs-bin but it is not going to be installed
>          Depends: xdg-utils but it is not going to be installed
>   ~>nginx-full : Depends: nginx-common (= 1.6.2-5+deb8u2) but it is not going to be installed
>                Depends: libgd3 (>= 2.1.0~alpha~) but it is not going to be installed
>   ~>E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a > solution).

I understand what is the problem here, It's the solution that is bugging me. Is there a simple way to say "hey, please install all of these" or not really? :)

Comment: "Try 'apt-get -f install'" you have this solution inside your question.

Comment: Nope. Same response

Comment: As explained in  [our guide to writing better questions](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3609/37681) please edit into your question that you did as suggested and ran `apt-get -f install` and the results of that. (Don't rely on ephemeral comments to hold useful info)

Comment: The message explicitly told you to run `apt-get -f install` _with no package names_. But you didn't do that. Please try again.

Comment: @Navern (and Michael Hampton) - I apologise, please make your comment an answer and I will accept it. I must have been doing something wrong, it worked today! Thanks for the effort once again.

Comment: i make an answer however i would just drop this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apt-get install -f` without specifying any package name should fix your issues and install required dependencies.

Comment: Could you expand? Is it dangerous running -f?

Comment: you could man apt-get install for further explanation. In short -f means to fix broken dependecies and it should be safe to run like that, however sometimes it wouldn't be enough.